# Permission denied when trying to append a file to a root owned file with sudo

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command-line, sudo

This is the shell command that results in "Permission denied" when I'm trying to append the data in a file to another file with sudo:

```
sudo cat add_file >> /etc/file
```

The file at `/etc/file` is owned by `root` (i.e. me) and its permissions are `rw-r--r--`. Should I become `root` for a moment to make it work or is there a workaround for `sudo`?

Comment: I think this question should be migrated to http://unix.stackexchange.com/ - It is not a programming question.

Answer (score 69, accepted):

Run `bash` as `sudo`:

```
$ sudo bash -c "cat add_file >> /etc/file"

$ whoami;sudo bash -c "whoami";whoami
iiSeymour
root
iiSeymour
```

Comment: Can you please explain why `sudo cat add_file >> /etc/file` doesn't work? I don't understand

Comment: Because the file redirection has to be done first. Imagine the case where `sudo cat file` was executed first, the file would be displayed to stdout. When we try to redirect with `>> /etc/file` it would be to late. It's same reason `cat file > file` produces an empty file.

Comment: So this is something like `sudo (cat add_file >> etc/file)`, thanks

Answer (score 27):

Try doing this instead :

```
sudo tee -a /etc/file < add_file
```

It's lighter than running bash or `sh -c command`

Comment: Maybe lighter but `sudo bash` isn't limited to this specific application, anyway +1 from me.

Comment: The problem with this method (compared to the other ones) is that file `add_file` needs to be readable by the user. But if file is readable by the user, it's shorter and more efficient that launching a whole new `bash` or `sh`.

Comment: You may want to use `sudo tee -a /etc/file < add_file > /dev/null` to silence the output to terminal (especially useful if the file being added is large or non text)

Answer (score 9):

A funny possibility is to use `ed` (the standard editor):

```
sudo ed -s /etc/file <<< $'r add_file\nwq'
```

I know I won't get upvoted for this wonderful answer, but I wanted to include it here anyway (because it's funny). Done!

Answer (score 5):

You are trying to write the result of the command `sudo cat add_file` to the file /etc/file. And apparently you don't have that right.

`man sudo` gives that example :

> ```
>    To make a usage listing of the directories in the /home partition.  Note
>    that this runs the commands in a sub-shell to make the cd and file
>    redirection work.
>
>     $ sudo sh -c "cd /home ; du -s * | sort -rn > USAGE"
> ```

So you should try :

`sudo sh -c "cat add_file >> /etc/file"`

Comment: Nothing new, sudo_O said that already.

Comment: I think the other answer lacks of explanation, it just gives a solution. In a first place I wanted to add my first sentence as a comment but it was too long with the man quote.

Answer (score 1):

Similar approach to [@gniourf_gniourf](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13778998/55075) answer, but using `ex`:

```
sudo ex +"r in.txt" -cwq out.txt
```

which is equivalent to  `vi`/`vim` Ex-mode (`-e`).

This in-place edit example is simple, safe and convenient approach, because it doesn't use any shell piping, FIFOs or shell within the shell workarounds.

To boost performance for scripting purposes, consider using silence mode (`-s`).

Answer (score -2):

try

```
sudo bash -c 'cat add_file >> /etc/file'
```

or

```
cat add_file | sudo tee -a /etc/file > /dev/null
```