# Run shell command and send output to file?

Tags: php, linux, bash

I need to be able to modify my openvpn auth file via a php script.  I have made my http user a no-pass sudoer, as this machine is only available within my home network.

I currently have the following commands:

```
echo shell_exec("sudo echo '".$username."' > /etc/openvpn/auth.txt");
echo shell_exec("sudo echo '".$password."' >> /etc/openvpn/auth.txt");
```

but when run, they do not change the file at all, or provide any output in php.

How do I make this work?

Comment: cant you use file_put_contents?

Comment: @marabutt: permissions won't allow

Comment: How do you run the script?

Comment: @zerkms: running from browser, via lighttpd and php-fpm

Comment: @Greg Schoppe: if you run this script with `sudu -u http ...` does it work?

Comment: @zerkms: would that be  `su http sudo echo "p19878787887" > /etc/openvpn/auth.txt`, because that doesn't seem to work, but `sudo -u http sudo echo "p19878787887" > /etc/openvpn/auth.txt` does.

Comment: @Greg Schoppe: `sudo -u http php file.php` ?

Comment: @zerkms: tells me `# sudo -u http php /srv/http/test.php
sh: /etc/openvpn/auth.txt: Permission denied
sh: /etc/openvpn/auth.txt: Permission denied`

Comment: Your situation is very similar to this one: http://stackoverflow.com/a/3166229/342740

Comment: ah! success!  the pipe to file isn't being run as sudo, only the echo command!  fixed by `echo shell_exec("sudo sh -c 'echo \"username\" > /etc/openvpn/auth.txt'");` running a new shell as root, then running the command in that.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13778857/permission-denied-when-trying-to-append-a-file-to-a-root-owned-file-with-sudo/13778926#13778926

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run

```
sudo command > file
```

Only the command is run as sudo, not redirection.

As you pointed out, `sudo sh -c "command > file"` would work. But unless, you really want to run the `command` as sudo, you should not do it. You can run only redirection part as sudo.
The answer by rici covers 2 methods to do it. Here is another method:

```
command | sudo tee filename >/dev/null #to overwrite (command > file)
command | sudo tee -a filename >/dev/null # to append (command >> file)
```

Comment: I should have added this as comment to other option, but I had already typed half of this answer. So posted here itself.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of running an entire shell process as root, which is arguably unsafe, you can run the copy as root:

(with bash):

```
sudo cp <(echo "$username") /etc/openvpn/auth.txt
```

(should work with any shell):

```
echo "$username" | sudo dd of=/etc/openvpn/auth.txt
```

Comment: I understand how this would give me username, but the file has to be two lines, username on one, password on the other... how would i do this, without being able to append?

Comment: @GregSchoppe: `{echo foo; echo bar; } | dd of=/path/to/file `. Or just put the entire string, including a newline character, between quotes: `echo "foo<newline>bar"`, which should be easy if you're generting the command line with php. If you really need to append and you're using GNU dd: `dd of=/path/to/file conv=notrunc oflag=append`.