# Shell script with sudo sh

Tags: bash, shell

I want to make a script to install a program (ROS) and I need to write this line:

```
 sudo sh -c 'echo "TEXT VARIABLE TEXT" > systemFile'  # to write in systemaFile I need sudo sh
```

if echo is just fixed text, it works. 
If echo is text + variable it doesn't work.

I've tried with:

```
read f1 < <(lsb_release -a | grep Code* | cut  -f2)   #codename is writted in variable $f1
echo $f1 # retruns "quantal" as I expected
sudo sh -c 'echo "TEXT $f1 TEXT" > systemFile'  #f1 is empty, WHY?
```

Then I have to assign the variable inside the same instruction sudo sh, for example:

sudo sh -c ' read f1 < <(lsb_release -a | grep Code* | cut  -f2) ; echo "TEXT $f1 TEXT" > systemFile'

sh: 1: Syntax error: redirection unexpected

Comment: & regd why your command does not work: variable expansions don't happen inside single quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try just like this script line

```
sudo sh -c 'echo TEXT '$f1' TEXT > systemFile'
sudo bash -c 'echo TEXT '$f1' TEXT > systemFile'
```

i have use this able script line in .sh file and its working fine.

Answer (score 2):

This can work too:

```
sudo sh -c "echo 'TEXT $VARIABLE TEXT' > systemFile"
```

However, it is generally not recommended to un-necessarily run a command as sudo. You seem to want only redirection to be "`sudo`ed". So try these options:

```
echo "TEXT $VARIABLE TEXT" | sudo tee systemFile >/dev/null
echo "TEXT $VARIABLE TEXT" | sudo dd of=systemFile
```

`echo` can be simple echo, or any other command you want. Note that this command is not being run under `sudo`.

Comment: # to write in systemaFile I need sudo sh - already mention in question

Comment: ^^ NO. try the `sudo dd`/`sudo tee` options. You don't need to use `sudo` for `sh`.

Comment: Check this question for other options : http://stackoverflow.com/q/17396951#answers

Answer (score 1):

use `-E` option to run `sudo`:

```
sudo -E sh -c 'echo "TEXT VARIABLE TEXT" > systemFile'
```

from `man sudo`:

> **-E**
>
> The -E (preserve environment) option indicates to the security policy that the user wishes to preserve their existing environment variables.  The security policy may return an error if the -E option is specified and the user does not have permission to preserve the environment.

Answer (score 0):

Shell variables are only expanded in "double quotes", not in 'single quotes'.

```
$ v=value

$ echo $v
value

$ echo "$v"
value

$ echo '$v'
$v
```

You're starting a new instance of `sh` which then runs the command `echo "TEXT $f1 TEXT" > systemFile`.

Since `$f1` has not been assigned within the new process, it's empty.

---

To fix this, you can expand `$f1` and pass it in the command line:
`sudo sh -c 'echo "TEXT '$f1' TEXT" > systemFile'`

**Or** export it so it's available to the child process (using `-E` to preserve the environment, thanks anishsane):
`export f1`
`sudo -E sh -c 'echo "TEXT $f1 TEXT" > systemFile'`

Comment: `sudo` does not pass `export`s to its children it seems. Same command without sudo prints properly when exported.

Comment: On another note, `'echo "TEXT '$f1' TEXT"` should be `'echo "TEXT '"$f1"' TEXT"`, in case `$f1` contains spaces or special characters.

Comment: @anishsane ah, I forgot you need the `-E` flag to preserve env vars. But no, it works fine without the extra double quotes for me.

Comment: as per your instruction i have try and results like #f1 is empty, WHY?